# How change theme for BottomSheetDialog in runtime

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I show BottomSheetDialog like:

```
dialog = BottomSheetDialog(ctx, R.style.DialogTheme)
dialog.setContentView(R.lauout.dialog)
dialog.show()

<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

<style name="DarkDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog"/>
```

I need to change DialogTheme theme to DarkDialogTheme in runtime.
I need to change theme when dialog was hidden ( dialog.hide() ), but dialog was not canceled.
Help me fix it.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Is the constructor BottomSheetDialog(ctx, theme) not enough?

Comment: I need to change theme when dialog was hidden ( dialog.hide() ), but dialog was not canceled